# svn, eclipse and folder outside workspace

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm quite new to svn and stuff so this may sound silly but thats my problem:
I have some folders with statics content of my webpage (img, css, js) under the eclipse workspace and connected with my team repository with help of subclipse. Now when I'd like to make some change locally to test it, I need to copy the static content to Apache's **htdocs** from workspace. Is is possible to connect workspace folder with folder in htdocs so when automaticlly when I save change in eclipse, the htdocs content is refreshed? As far as I know, making new folder, as linked folder in Eclipse won't work. Any suggestion? I have also tortoisesvn, and i'm working under windows xp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to just change Apache virtual hosts to point your project folder as the base directory instead of having 2 copies of the same thing and syncing.

Something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/workspace/"
    ServerName  your.server.name
</VirtualHost>
```

And restarting apache will make your browser to resolve the url: `your.server.name/css/somefile.css` from your project directory.
If you want to use localhost or 127.0.0.1 just remove the ServerName line, but don't leave this without server name and the main virtual host because that will generate conflicts.

Comment: Could you help me with small example? Let's say the statics css is placed under C:/workspace/css dir, how should I describe vitual host for apache?